# Java generics incompatible types (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist)

Tags: java, generics

That's basically my first touch with Java generic types and I can't figure out what is wrong with the following piece of code.

I have a helper class `Helper` with a static function `inRange` usng generic type that should return the list of objects from an input list that are in certain `range` around object at index `index` (I haven't tested it yet, it's not an issue here if it works correctly or not):

```
public class Helper {
public static <T> List<T> inRange(List<T> list, int index, int range) {
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<T>();
    int N = list.size();
    assert(index < N);
    if (N == 0)
        return res;
    int i, j;

    /* right range */
    i = (index + 1) % N;
    j = 0;
    while (i != index && j < range) {
        res.add(list.get(i));
        i = (i + 1) % N;
        j++;
    }

    /* left range */
    i = (N + index - 1) % N;
    j = 0;
    while (i != index && j < range && !res.contains(list.get(i))) {
        res.add(lista.get(i));
        i = (N + i - 1) % N;
        j++;
    }

    return res;
}
}
```

Then I want to use it in a class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StrategyA extends StrategyB {
public Decision makeDecision(GameView gameView, Action action, View playerView) {
    int pos = gameView.activePlayersViews().indexOf(playerView);
    assert(pos != -1);

    ArrayList<View> inRange = Helper.inRange(gameView.activePlayersViews(), pos, 
            playerView.range());
    // todo ...
    return new Decision(Decision.KindOfDecision.DO_NOTHING, 0);

}
}
```

where `gameView.activePlayersView()` is of type `ArrayList<View>`.

Then from my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) on the line calling `inRange(..)` I get

`Error:(8, 56) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.List<T> conforms to java.util.ArrayList<View>`

Even I change generic type `T` directly to `View` I still get this error

Comment: `inRange` returns `List`, not `ArrayList`

Comment: For starters `inRange` does return a `List` and you are trying to assign it to `ArrayList`. This is not possible, although I'd expect a different error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minimize your example like (using Integer of the templated List type):

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> inRange = Helper.inRange(list, 0,1);
    }
}

class Helper {
    public static <T> List<T> inRange(List<T> list, int index, int range) {
        List<T> res = new ArrayList<T>();
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then even if you put template types out of the picture:

```
ArrayList inRange = Helper.inRange(list, 0,1);

public static List inRange(List list, int index, int range) { ... }
```

you see that while the helper static method returns a List, you are trying to assign it to an ArrayList, and that's your problem, as ArrayList is a concrete implementation of List, but you cannot assign a reference to a generic List to a concrete implementation of ArrayList

Just change to:

```
List<View> inRange = Helper.inRange(gameView.activePlayersViews(), pos, 
        playerView.range());
```

and you are good to go: https://ideone.com/MXZxqz

Answer (score 10):

`ArrayList` is an implementation of `List` interface.
So all `ArrayList` instances are `List` instances but all `List` instances are not necessarily `ArrayList`.

So when you call this method :

```
public static <T> List<T> inRange(List<T> list, int index, int range) {
```

you cannot assign its result to an `ArrayList` as you are doing :

```
ArrayList<View> inRange = Helper.inRange(...);
```

Go on to program by interface and use `List` in both sides :

```
List<View> inRange = Helper.inRange(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens, because `inRange()` returns type `List<T>`. You can store result in reference with type `List` or any supertype.

Try to use this code:

```
List<View> inRange = Helper.inRange(gameView.activePlayersView(), pos, 
            playerView.range());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do:

```
List<View> inRange = Helper.inRange(gameView.activePlayersView(), pos, 
        playerView.range());
```

And check this:

```
res.add(lista.get(i));
```

there is no lista in this class

Comment: No lista coz I manually translated it from my native lang identifiers. Solution helped anyway, tks

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the type `ArrayList` to be `List`

```
ArrayList<View> inRange = Helper.inRange((List<View>) gameView.activePlayersViews(), pos, 
playerView.range());
```